# Programmatically Generate a Button in VBA Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA to generate a button programmatically in a userform. However I have successfully to create a button in the userform and also put codes for the button click event, but the button doesn't run the code under the commandbutton_click(). Would anyone can help me to debug my codes?

An error is ocurring at "Set NewCommandButton1 = MyUserForm.Desinger.Controls.Add("forms.CommandButton.1")" with the error code of "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)"

Million thanks

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim X As Long
Dim MyUserForm As Object
Dim NewCommandButton1 As MSForms.CommandButton

Set MyUserForm = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm3")
Set NewCommandButton1 = MyUserForm.Desinger.Controls.Add("forms.CommandButton.1")

With NewCommandButton1

.Caption = "Welcome"
.Height = 18
.Width = 44
.Left = 147
.Top = 6

End With

With MyUserForm.CodeModule

X = .CountOfLines
.InsertLines X + 1, "Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
.InsertLines X + 2, "    MsgBox ""Hello"""
.InsertLines X + 3, "End Sub"

End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code to create controls.

```
Private Function CreateControl(ByVal Ctype As String, ByVal Cname As String, ByVal Cwidth As Single, ByVal Cheight As Single, ByVal Ctop As Single, ByVal Cleft As Single) As MSForms.Control
    ' 014.8013.1.0
    Set CreateControl = Controls.Add("Forms." & Ctype & ".1")
    With CreateControl
    If Len(Cname) Then .Name = Cname
    .Width = Cwidth
    .Height = Cheight
    .Top = Ctop
    .Left = Cleft
    End With
End Function
```

Note that the Ctype argument could be "Commandbutton".
The difference with your code seems to be in the dimensioning. you have `Dim NewCommandButton1 As MSForms.CommandButton` whereas I use `Dim NewCommandButton1 As MSForms.Control`. Another is in the specification of `Desinger` in the Add method. I think this is from VB, not VBA, and mis-spelled as well. Your code is ambiguous about MyUserForm. By nature, this should be `Me` which is likely the default and why my code doesn't even have it.

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer, then. (It's that green checkmark below the ratings)